# Query that converts a timestamp to a date

Tags: database, datetime

Is it possible to convert a timestamp to a date format in a query?

This is the code I am using.

```
$query = db_select('my_submissions', 's');
$query->fields('s', array('sid','name','company','email','phone','is_customer','submitted','count'));
$entries = $query->execute();

$rows = array();
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
  $row = array_map('check_plain', (array) $entry);
  $row['submitted'] = $row['submitted'] ? date('d.m.Y H:i', $row['submitted']) : "";
  $rows[] = $row;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$select->addExpression("DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(submitted), '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i')", 'submitted_formatted');
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp

then in your loop, reference it as $row['submitted_formatted'];

Comment: This won't take into account the user's timezone.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL allows converting a timestamp into a formatted date, using the [FROM_UNIXTIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) function.

In your case, instead of the 'submitted' field, you might add an expression to the query with the [addExpression method](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3AaddExpression/7.x), in the following way:

```
$query->addExpression("FROM_UNIXTIME(submitted, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i')");
```

Comment: This won't take into account the user's timezone.

Answer (score 0):

While

```
$select->addExpression("DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(yourDBcolumn), '%d.%M.%Y')", 'c.yourDBcolumn_formatted');
```

Does indeed work, this is definitely not best practice if you're displaying this on a page/block.

A themer/front-end dev shouldn't have to go into PHP code to change the format of the date.

It's best practice for your custom module to have a template file where they can easily format it with Twig's `|date` filter

```
{{ mydate|date }}           <!-- November 17, 2019 23:12 -->
{{ mydate|date('d/m/Y') }}  <!-- 17/11/2019 -->
```

Also, you could add timezone here, ex:

```
{{ mydate|date('d/m/Y', 'Europe/Paris') }}
```